# Arduino Nano/Uno and js sketch compiling/uploading from browser

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, compile, node.js

I need to compile generated source code in js runtime then upload it to my device.

#### Compiling:

I have found [arduino-cli](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-cli)

#### Uploading:

There is only [avrgirl](https://github.com/noopkat/avrgirl-arduino) but it doesn't work in browser. What should I do?

Comment: Arduinos cannot be programmend in Nodejs. You need to write C/C++ or Assembler.

Comment: @chrisl, it's not about programming (code is c-generated one) it's about calling compiler from js

Comment: Ah, ok. But you can also upload sketches with arduino-cli. If you can use it, you can also upload sketches

Answer (score 1):

You can't, and that's a good thing. If the browser could let a Web site access your hardware, that would be a huge security breach. You may be able to bypass this security restriction if you can write an extension (plugin) for your browser.

Comment: Okay then I will use extension for hex code uploading. Then how can I compile it using only in-browser js?

Comment: I mean: source code -> String -> Compiler -> Hex-string -> Extension -> Uploading

Comment: @caxapexac: Building a C++ compiler in JavaScript is not a trivial task. You may try to port avr-g++ using [Emscripten](https://emscripten.org/).

Comment: Seems for me a weird way to do everything in the browser. Normally in such a situation you are actually building a web service, so the compilation could be done server side by calling avr-g++ or arduino-cli through the nodejs code. Then you only would need to encapsule arduino-cli in an extention for uploading on the local computer

Comment: I modify the code from js-stk500 to work from browser with web serial API. but I can't makr Arduino CLI to work in browser. Is that possible?